# use brick texture node as an overlay to simulate tiling

Tags: node-editor

Premise: I'm totally new to renders in Blender. I'm trying to use it in my daily workflow, please be gentle

I need to use and change materials in my models quickly. So I thought "brick texture" node would be the best way to simulate tiling on different materials, overlaying the mortar on a base texture. If I need to change material I could change only the "base texture".

I found I'm not able to overlay the mortar to a sandard texture. I've looked everywhere for a tutorial or similar, but found none.

This is the node structure I expected to work, but ...

[image]

Comment: Hello, Ssimple, and welcome. What kind of tiling? Square? Irregular?  Offset?  Please illustrate with a representative sample of the possibilities.

Comment: My first thought would be to use _Multiply_ instead of _Add_ for your mix color node.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the mortar to be overlaying the *Image Texture* - without the varying colors of the bricks, just the mortar?

First of all, I see you've set the brick colors to white with an alpha value of 0 to make them transparent. This doesn't do anything, the *Mix RGB* node (or *Mix Color* in current Blender versions) will only use the RGB information and ignore the alpha.

So to overlay the mortar over an image, use the *Fac* output of the *Brick Texture* node and plug it into the *Fac* input of the *Mix RGB*. The *Fac* value is 0 or black where the bricks are and 1 or white where the mortar is. Any *Color1*, *Color2* and *Mortar* color settings for the bricks are irrelevant.

Now you can plug the *Image Texture* into the *Color1* input of the *Mix RGB* node (or input *A* on a *Mix Color* node) and choose any color you want for the mortar in the second input. Even a different texture if you want.

The *Mix RGB* node should be set to *Mix*, this way the brick areas will only show the texture and the mortar areas will show the second color (I used red to make it more obvious, you can choose any color).

[image: mortar overlay]

This is to completely replace the image where the mortar is. Of course other mix modes can be used, too. For example to colorize the image with the mortar color by darkening it you can use *Multiply*. Colorizing and brightening it with the mortar you can do by using *Add*. To colorize the image in varying shades in the bricks you can change by taking the *Color* output of the *Brick Texture* instead of *Fac* (but in this case you might want to switch the mortar color to white instead of black). Or you can check out all other modes to see what they are doing.

Examples:

[image: mixing examples]